# Merge multiple data frames with different dimensions using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frames (in reality they are more than 3).

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'head1': ['foo', 'bix', 'bar'],'val': [11, 22, 32]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'head2': ['foo', 'xoo', 'bar','qux'],'val': [1, 2, 3,10]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'head3': ['xoo', 'bar',],'val': [20, 100]})
# Note that the value in column 'head' is always unique
```

What I want to do is to merge them based on `head` column. And whenever the value of a `head` does not exist in one data frame we would assign it with NA.

In the end it'll look like this:

```
         head1   head2  head3
 -------------------------------
 foo     11      1       NA
 bix     22      NA      NA
 bar     32      3      100
 xoo     NA      2      20
 qux     NA      10     NA
```

How can I achieve that using Pandas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) selecting the `axis=1` to concatenate your multiple DataFrames.

Note however that I've first set the index of the `df1, df2, df3` to use the variables (foo, bar, etc) rather than the default integers.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'head1': ['foo', 'bix', 'bar'],'val': [11, 22, 32]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'head2': ['foo', 'xoo', 'bar','qux'],'val': [1, 2, 3,10]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'head3': ['xoo', 'bar',],'val': [20, 100]})

df1 = df1.set_index('head1')
df2 = df2.set_index('head2')
df3 = df3.set_index('head3')


df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1)

columns = ['head1', 'head2', 'head3']
df.columns = columns

print(df)

     head1  head2  head3
bar     32      3    100
bix     22    NaN    NaN
foo     11      1    NaN
qux    NaN     10    NaN
xoo    NaN      2     20
```