# Convert row names into a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas [data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445214/1380929):

```
print(df)

     head1  head2  head3
bar     32      3    100
bix     22    NaN    NaN
foo     11      1    NaN
qux    NaN     10    NaN
xoo    NaN      2     20
```

What I want to do is to convert the row names `bar, bix, ...` into columns such that 
in the end I have something like this:

```
    newhead     head1  head2  head3
0   bar         32      3    100
1   bix         22    NaN    NaN
2   foo         11      1    NaN
3   qux         NaN    10    NaN
4   xoo         NaN     2     20
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
df.index.name = 'newhead'
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

yields

```
  newhead  head1  head2  head3
0     bar     32      3    100
1     bix     22    NaN    NaN
2     foo     11      1    NaN
3     qux    NaN     10    NaN
4     xoo    NaN      2     20
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in one line.

```
df.rename_axis("newhead").reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi, @florian, Could you show me the version of your pandas package.

Comment: @florian, the code is ok, maybe you should try:
df = df.rename_axis("newhead").reset_index()